# Image is corrupted after PIL's tobytes() method

Tags: python, image, cloud, python-imaging-library

I want to upload an image to a Google Bucket, however I want to reduce the size of the image before uploading. When I don't call the self._resize_image method the image gets successfully uploaded without any problems. However, when I call the resize method it works until the image.tobytes() method. After the image.tobytes() method is called the image can't be read anymore.

```
def _resize_image(self, image: bytes, base_with: int = 300) -> bytes:
    stream = BytesIO(image)
    image = Image.open(stream).convert("RGBA")
    width_percentage = base_with / float(image.size[0])
    height_size = int(float(image.size[1]) * float(width_percentage))
    image = image.resize((base_with, height_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    # if I do image.show() here the picture is still displayed correctly.
    return image.tobytes()  # after this line the picture is getting uploaded, but can't be read by Google anymore.

def upload_image_to_bucket(self, image: bytes, bucket_folder: str, compress: bool = True) -> str:
    if compress:
        # if I don't call this method the picture get's uploaded correctly.
        image = self._resize_image(image=image)
    file_name = f"{UUIDService().create_uuid(length=40)}.jpeg"
    bucket = self._client.storage.bucket()
    blob = bucket.blob(f"{bucket_folder}/{file_name}")
    blob.upload_from_string(data=image, content_type="image/jpeg")
    return file_name
```

Comment: How did you determine that the image is corrupted?

Comment: "I tried to debug manually and Googling about the tobytes method, but haven't found anything so far. " When you searched like that, did you find [the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html)? Do you see the shaded-background warning given for the `tobytes` method? Do you see how that relates to the problem? Did you try following the advice given in that warning? (Hint: what kind of file do you want to create via this process?) If you did not find the documentation, then what exactly did you put into the search query?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I saw the warning, but I seemed to not have minded that enough. I thought since I use the upload_from_string later on to upload it, I can ignore it. Seems I was wrong :(

Comment: @decorator-factory Well, I tried to open it again, but it failed :P

Comment: "I thought since I use the upload_from_string later on to upload it, I can ignore it." This is a question of a lack of understanding. The problem is not that the "raw image data" (as the documentation puts it) is a `bytes` object rather than a file - afterall, the workaround being suggested involves `BytesIO`, from which you can extract the underlying `bytes` again. The problem is the *format of the data*. Please make sure you have a general understanding of *how computers represent images*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Pillow's documentation on `tobytes`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes):

> This method returns the raw image data from the internal storage. For compressed image data (e.g. PNG, JPEG) use save(), with a BytesIO parameter for in-memory data.

So the `tobytes()` method returns Pillow's internal representation of the image, presumably to be restored with `frombytes()`. If you want to save the image as JPEG, use [the `save()` method](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) as suggested by the documentation:

```py
output = BytesIO()
image.save(output, format="jpeg")
... # do something with `output`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the tobytes() function gives raw uncompressed bytes. You would have use PIL's save function to save into a buffer and then upload that.

```
output = io.BytesIO()
img.save(output, format='JPEG')
```

Answer (score -2):

It may be the Image.ANTIALIAS function; try leaving that field blank.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).